# I am receiving a message stating "unknown device" when i plug a usb or external hard-drive in my computer.

Tags: windows, drivers, usb-storage, device-manager, micro-sd-card

I am having an issue with USB drives and Windows.  When any external media device is attached to the computer in Device Manager I receive the message  `unknown USB device`.

This happens with USB drives and MicroSD/SD cards. I tested the USB drivers and they worked fine on another computer.  I made sure I properly ejected it (safely remove device) too. My USB devices use to be recognized on my computer before.

Why is this happening and what can I do to correct it?

Comment: Which Version of Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many people also having similar problems with Windows not recognizing USB devices.
The issue is with `.inf` files.

- Copy the entire `C:\Windows\INF` folder to `C:\usb_fix` or (whatever folder name you like to call it)
- Go back into Device Manager. Select the "Unknown USB device"
- Choose *Update Driver*
- Select *Choose Location*
- Enter the path of the new folder you have created earlier.
- Windows will now search for the driver in this folder location instead of the previously selected one.
- You should see your device being recognized – now you're able to open them in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that the problems occur to both SD and USB, the common denominator is your motherboard. You can always used windows to install/upgrade your motherboard's chipset drivers, but you should preferably look for your motherboard drivers online (If it is a notebook, just look for the model and you'll find the updated drivers). Even if it was working correctly, the drivers could have been corrupted somehow.